# error while invoking lambda function through CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, faas

I am new to lambda, succeeded in creating lambda functions through console and triggered them.
but when i am trying to invoke them using AWS CLI, i am facing issues.

my lambda function (python) is simple and just prints the input arguments and tested successfully in console.

i am calling like below in cli from a windows machine,

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name testfn --invocation-type RequestResponse --payload '{"a":"b"}' outfile.txt
```

the error says - Invalid base64: "'{a:b}'"

But if i give an empty payload like -

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name testfn --invocation-type RequestResponse --payload '{}' outfile.txt
```

it is getting succceded with below output.

```
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

So what is going wrong with my payload? Please help.

What does this error mean ? Invalid base64: "'{a:b}'"

I had also tried giving payload from a json file and passing that file with exact path in the command, still same error.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for.. thanks a ton. In my case I had to use a seperate json file along with the solution provided in the link for payload.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the payload should be [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

This requirement is one of the **breaking changes** in AWS CLI v2:

- [AWS CLI version 2 now passes binary parameters as base64-encoded strings by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html#cliv2-migration-binaryparam) .

`invoke` payload is of type `blob`. In AWS CLI v2:

> By default, the AWS CLI version 2 now passes all binary input and binary output parameters as **base64-encoded** strings. A parameter that requires binary input has its type specified as **blob** (binary large object) in the documentation.